# How can I specify the post status of an untrashed post?

Tags: filters, actions, post-status, trash

By default Wordpress assigns the `draft` status to a post that has been untrashed. I would like to assign the `pending` status to posts that are untrashed.

This seems to be possible with [wp_untrash_post_status](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_untrash_post_status/), but I can't seem to find the proper way to use it. I have this in my code :

```
add_action( 'untrash_post', 'my_function' );
function my_function( $post_id ) {
  apply_filters( 'wp_untrash_post_status', 'pending', $post_id, 'pending' );
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for your purpose `wp_untrash_post_status` filter will be enough. Will work with single and multiple posts restore.

> Filters the status that a post gets assigned when it is restored from the trash (untrashed).

```
add_filter( 'wp_untrash_post_status', 'change_untrash_post_status');

function change_untrash_post_status($status){
    return 'pending';
}
```

P.S. `apply_filters`hook is used to call callback functions created by us, like a snippet above, so `apply_filters` will fire a callback function which we added with `add_filter` (As I understood wp logic right)